# Convert a signed Int to a hex string with spaces

Tags: c++, c, string, int

I was wondering if I could get some help converting a integer to a hex string with a space between each byte like so-

```
int val = -2147483648;
char hexval[32];

sprintf(hexval, "%x", val)

Output = 80000000
```

how could I add spaced between each byte so I would have a string like -> 80 00 00 00

is there an easier way then malloc'ing memory and moving a pointer around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple function:

```
/**
 * hexstr(char *str, int val);
 * 
 * `str` needs to point to a char array with at least 12 elements.
**/
int hexstr(char *str, int val) {
    return snprintf(str, 12, "%02hhx %02hhx %02hhx %02hhx", val >> 24, val >> 16, val >> 8, val);
}
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/AnE2AO):

```
int main(void) {
    int val = -2147483648;
    char hexval[12];

    hexstr(hexval, val);
    printf("Integer value: %d\n", val);
    printf("Result string: %s\n", hexval);

    return 0;
}
```

> Integer value: -2147483648
>   Result string: 80 00 00 00

Comment: @Gopi Whoops, thought I fixed that before copying here but apparently not.

Comment: Why not just add spaces in the buffer instead of doing the shifting  operations?

Comment: Not dynamic, what if `val = 1`? Output will prefixed with extra zero's. `00 00 00 01`.

Comment: I was over thinking way too hard about this, thank you for bringing back to earth.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you may consider using `std::hex`. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n=255;
    std::cout << std::hex << n << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

A more flexible implementation that do not rely on printing the content can be

```
void gethex(int n, std::ostream &o) {
    o << std::hex << n;
}
```

then

```
std::ostringstream ss;
gethex(myNumber, ss);
std::cout << "Hex number: " << ss.str() << std::endl;
```

Comment: But this doesn't store it in a string, however. So you should use a `stringstream` instead of `cout`.